# Assign IP address to example.com

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx

I'm setting up DNS on Snow Leopard Server and I'm having an issue. I'm able to link an IP address with a subdomain such as www.example.com just fine, but how can I link one to just example.com?

My current DNS provider lets me use a @ for the subdomain and that acts like example.com, but Snow Leopard Server complains when I enter this in. I can only use numbers, letters, and hyphens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the zone was example.com. The solution was pretty simple; I just added an A record with example.com. as the FQDN, added an IP and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

"@" represents second + first level domain name, so yours ISP told you correct.

don't enter anything in just create an empty A record with your IP.

Comment: It said that a name value for the A record is required

Comment: try http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/1436